# Where to view output of echo for server side php in firefox?

Tags: php, firefox, frontend

Total newb question.  I am running a web server that calls some php scripts.  The scripts have echo statements, but I am not sure how to view the output.  I checked in the console in Firefox's developer tools, but didn't see anything.

Comment: You need to learn the basics. The console is for client events and actions. Echo's and prints will be sent from the server as output, i.e. will appear as page content. They are also viewable in the page's source code.

Answer (score 0):

What `echo` Does is it outputs it on to the webpage. If you want to put something in the console, you're going to want to use JavaScript `console.log("Hello world!);` and echo that like this:

```
echo "<script>console.log('Hey!');</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 for previous answers.

w3schools.com is your friend.  Run through their tutorials to get started.